# Iterate over source page with cheerio and performing logic

Tags: javascript, html, cheerio

I want to be able to perform some logic across all the HTML in the source page using `cheerio`. I'm not sure how to do this as I can't seem to find a method that can do this in the [cheerio library](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). I think the closest method is the `.each()` [method](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-). However, it seems like I need to have a tag to match with first. I want to perform logic to EVERY piece of HTML.

This is what I have so far:

```
    let $ = cheerio.load(pageSource);
```

This is the function I want to apply to every tag and its contents:

```
    summarizeContent(content) {
        let contentLength = content.length;
        let middle = " ....... ";
        if ((contentLength> this.contentSummarizeMinLength) && (contentLength < this.contentSummarizeMaxLength)) {
            let chunkIndex = 0;
            const increment = 5;
            while (contentLength > this.contentSummarizeMinLength) {
                chunkIndex += increment;
                contentLength -= 2 * increment;
            }
            content = content.substring(0, chunkIndex) + middle + content.substr(-chunkIndex);
        } else if (contentLength >= this.contentSummarizeMaxLength) {
            const chunk = 20;
            content = content.substring(0, chunk) + middle + content.substr(-chunk);
        }
        return content;
    }
```

So after the HTML transform, I should have an output like this if this was my input:

```
<ul id="fruits">
    <li class="apple">AppleAppleAppleAppleAppleAppleAppleAppleApple</li>
    <li class="orange">OrangeOrangeOrangeOrangeOrangeOrangeOrange</li>
    <li class="pear">PearPearPearPearPearPearPearPearPearPearPearPear</li
</ul>
```

output:

```
<ul id="fruits">
    <li class="apple">AppleApple ...... AppleApple</li>
    <li class="orange">Orange ...... Orange</li>
    <li class="pear">PearPear ...... PearPear</li
</ul>
```

The content within the `<li>` tags don't matter. I just want to be able to apply a function to across some content between HTML tags. Usage of Cheerio is not required, it was the first library I found that I should would do the job.

Answer (score 5):

The HTML page is organized as a tree of nodes.  You need to walk through that tree and summarize any text nodes that you find while passing element nodes along to process their text nodes.  You can use a recursive function to do this.  For an element node you'll call the recursive function again, for a text node you'll call the `summarizeContent` function you wrote.

```
//You can find a list of node types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
var TEXT_NODE_TYPE = 3,
    ELEMENT_NODE_TYPE = 1;

function summarizeElementNode(node) {
    node.contents().each(function(ix, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        switch($el.nodeType) {
            case TEXT_NODE_TYPE:
                summarizeContent($el);
                break;

            case ELEMENT_NODE_TYPE:
                summarizeElementNode($el);
                break;
    });
}
```

Then, you only need to call `summarizeElementNode` on the document root.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(pageSource);
summarizeElementNode($.root());
```